# Menu folder in android studio disappeared?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am struggling to find the menu folder in android studio under res, but I cannot find it? how do i find it?

[image]

Comment: Just add one; also, are you looking at the Project or Android options in the IDE?

Comment: I am looking at the android options.

Comment: Switch to Project and if it is still missing, simply create one by Right-Clicking the res/ folder

Comment: It is still missing. I chose empty project at the beginning of creating an android project. I think that might be the reason why there is no menu.

Comment: Just create one or create one - yeah, I know I said the same thing twice. Or you can just delete this project and start over!

Comment: That is what I have done. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

One was not created for your project. Right-click over `res/`, and there will be an option for you to create a new resource directory.

Comment: @joey: It works for everybody else, at least through Android Studio 2.3.1.